# Pressure Regulator Operation

Tags: plumbing

How quickly should a PRV return to set pressure after water use?

Background: I have a new PRV set to 55 psi.  When I open a faucet the pressure drops to 40ish while the faucet is open, then when the faucet is closed it takes several minutes for the pressure to build back up to 55.  Is this normal?

According to irrigation district, the input runs between 100-200 psi.  I have verified that there are no leaks in the system.  PRV is a Watts LF 25AUB Z3

Comment: It sounds like it's set to 40 psi.

Comment: Are you saying the PRV is opening in routine operation?  PRVs are safety devices.  Do you consider it normal that the system goes above the "relief required" limit?